# Use a ternary operator in a variables string

Tags: php, ternary-operator, vbulletin

Is it possible to use a ternary operator inside of a variable that also is checking a variable, I'm not sure if that is the correct way to explain, so let me just show you what I mean.

```
$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/'.($vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl']) ? simple : postcard.'" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

This var is just checking whether the setting is on or off, and is a boolean returning a 1 or a zero

```
$vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl']
```

But that's useless information I just need to know how or if I can use a ternary operator here.

Basically I am trying to simplify this:

```
if ($vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl']) {
    $drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
  } else {
    $drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/postcard" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
  }
```

If this is possible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just enclose within brackets: `$drc_embed_vine =  '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/'.(($vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl']) ? "simple" : "postcard").'" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enclose those inside paranthesis. In addition, you are missing quotes for simple and postcard:

```
$drc_embed_vine = '<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/'.(($vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl']) ? "simple" : "postcard").'" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
                                                             ^                                               ^          ^         ^
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining =) just starting to use ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
$drc_embed_vine=($vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl'])?'<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/simple" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>':'<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/postcard" width="480" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

or  put some extra small parenthesis

```
$drc_embed_vine='<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/$2/embed/'.(($vbulletin->options['drc_embed_vine_smpl'])?'simple':'postcard')). width="480" height="480" frameborder="0">';
```